# Best personality inventory for employment and resources for learning it

Tags: personality, big-five

I am looking for different personality inventories (based on big five traits) that can be used for workplace. In addition I wanted to know where can I learn about administration of these questionnaires, their actual questions, and their interpretations? Are there any books, websites, etc

Regards

Comment: Be careful with this sort of thing. There are a lot more books than good science in this area.

Comment: @BryanKrause : Can you provide me with some good scientific references then?